# Stored Procedure in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to register query and call them by name to execute them. I am building an application that will let the user save search query associated with a label. I would like to save the query generated by the filter in ES.

Comment: [Search templates](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/search-template.html) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

[Search template](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/search-template.html) is the answer to that question. You can register queries and pass parameters using this mechanism.